# Problema com Build em modo release C#

Tags: c#, .net

Ao tentar fazer o build modo release exibe a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> O assembly de modo misto foi compilado em relação à versão 'v2.0.50727' do tempo de execução e não pode ser carregado no tempo de execução 4.0 sem informações de configuração adicionais

No arquivo: **SGEN**

Build no modo debug funciona sem problemas.

Alguém tem ideia do que posso fazer?

Comment: De uma olhada neste link.http://www.davidmoore.info/blog/2010/12/17/running-net-2-runtime-applications-under-the-net-4-runtime/

Comment: Eu já havia olhando este link, mas não resolveu. vlw

Comment: Solução: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bg162891.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Em App.config:

```
<startup>
...
</startup>
```

Modifique para:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
...
</startup>
```

Answer (score 3):

Por causa do suporte à *runtimes* em paralelo, a versão 4.0 da plataforma .NET mudou a maneira como o framework se vincula a antigos assemblies de modo misto (*mixed mode*).

Estes assemblies são, por exemplo, aqueles que são compilados a partir de C++\CLI. (Assemblies DirectX são também disponibilizados em modo misto.) Se você ver esta mensagem, saberá que esta é a causa do seu problema:

> O assembly de modo misto foi compilado em relação à versão
> 'v2.0.50727' do tempo de execução e não pode ser carregado no tempo de
> execução 4.0 sem informações de configuração adicionais.

Caso você queira retornar ao modo de vinculação utilizado no .NET 2.0, adicione a seguinte *flag* ao seu arquivo app.config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
</startup>
```

Fonte:

[F# Scripting, .NET 4.0 and Mixed-mode assemblies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jomo_fisher/f-scripting-net-4-0-and-mixed-mode-assemblies), Jomo Fisher

Answer (score 0):

Na opções do projeto na aba Build.
Na opção "Generate serialization assembly" deixar como auto.